# Authenticating using pre-shared secret

Tags: security, authentication, web-applications

We are working on a GWT web-application which requires secure user authentication. We have the possibility of providing The credentials to the user via fax. So we can use pre-shared secret. There is no possibility for us to use ssl or https in this app.

I was wondering what will be the more secure way to store the pass on the server and authenticate the user; should we hash the password two times, I suspect?

Comment: Why SSL and HTTPS are a no-no?

Comment: It is just because we assume it needs some change in the application design; isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If no encryption can be in place, you should hash the password on the client side (salted with a *random* salt provided by the server) and compare the resulting hash.

This approach has two advantages:

1. the hashed value is different each login
2. the password is never sent in plain text.

However, without encryption and *proper* authentication, session hijacking and such attacks are trivial.

*Please note that there is no way to make this **secure enough to foil any attack attempt** of a reasonably competent malicious party without some sort of encryption/authentiaction layer on top of http, so it is probably for the best not to give the users any sense of false security, mmkay?*

The biggest problem in the "let's only make the log-in as secure as possible" is that session side-jacking attack is rather trivial without encryption. Sidejacking (as defined in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking#Methods)) is:

> Session sidejacking, where the attacker uses packet sniffing to read network traffic between two parties to steal the session cookie. Many web sites use SSL encryption for login pages to prevent attackers from seeing the password, but do not use encryption for the rest of the site once authenticated. This allows attackers that can read the network traffic to intercept all the data that is submitted to the server or web pages viewed by the client. Since this data includes the session cookie, it allows him to impersonate the victim, even if the password itself is not compromised.[3] Unsecured Wi-Fi hotspots are particularly vulnerable, as anyone sharing the network will generally be able to read most of the web traffic between other nodes and the access point.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your helpful response;
In this way I should store the plain password (not a hashed version) on the server. is it right? It worries me a little bit about the pass security on the server.
Just another though; will it be safer to send a salt along with the user pass through fax in the start?

Comment: Regarding the HTTPS, I think eventually we have to enable it for the web-app due to the lack of security.